# How to insert Spaces in long Credit Card Number every X characters in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, credit-card

I seem to have some kind of lapsus...

How can I format a continuous credit card number to have blank space after every 4 digits in T-SQL?

```
TableName     | Cards                    |
ColumnName    | CardNumber               |
ExampleInput  | 80756201005803400471     | varchar(20)

ExampleOutput | 8075 6201 0058 0340 0471 | varchar(25)
```

I whish to have `ExampleOutput` in a `SELECT` statement, performance is irrelevant.

Comment: is the length always the same ?

Comment: Hope your not actually storing clear-text credit card numbers in your DB ...

Comment: Why are you dealing with presentation concerns deep down at the database layer?

Comment: it is probably easier to use your credit card number when it is stored this way :P

Comment: @all no worries, its not really CC numbers, it was just to popularize the example of a long number-string. It's a brown-field project where I need this kind of presentation-logic in a Stored Procedure unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(ccn, 17, 0, ' '), 13, 0, ' '), 9, 0, ' '), 5, 0, ' ')
```

That is, nested called to `stuff()`.  Note:  you need to start at the end of the string or else be very careful about the offsets.

Comment: Thanks to all, I went with this solution as I didn't even know about STUFF ... So happy I learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if the length is fixed:

```
Select *
    , SUBSTRING(n, 1, 4) + ' ' 
     + SUBSTRING(n, 5, 4) + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(n, 9, 4) + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(n, 13, 4) + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(n, 17, 4) + ' '
From (values('80756201005803400471')) as car(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an other perspecive by using `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING`.

**Query**

```
declare @num as varchar(50)
set @num = '80756201005803400471'

select left(@num,4) 
    + ' ' 
    + substring(@num,5,4) 
    + ' '
    + substring(@num,9,4) 
    + ' '
    +substring(@num,13,4) 
    + ' '
    +substring(@num,17,4);
```

And also can use a `RIGHT` function instead of the last `SUBSTRING`.

**Query**

```
declare @num as varchar(50)
set @num = '80756201005803400471'

select left(@num,4) 
    + ' ' 
    + substring(@num,5,4) 
    + ' '
    + substring(@num,9,4) 
    + ' '
    +substring(@num,13,4) 
    + ' '
    +right(@num,4);
```